# How to remove {} and [] from json column postgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I have column in postgreSQL with json data type. Until today there were not row which contained {} or [].

However, I start to see {} and [] due to new implementation. I want to remove it.

Example: Following is my table looks like. json is json data type

```
 id |       json       
----+------------------
  a | {"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.02"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.2" ...
----+------------------
 b  | {"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.32"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.47" ...
----+------------------
 d  | {}
----+------------------
 e  | []
```

Where I  want as following:

```
 id |       json       
----+------------------
  a | {"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.02"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.2" ...
----+------------------
 b  | {"st":[{"State": "TX", "Value":"0.32"}, {"State": "CA", "Value":"0.47" ...
```

How I should able to do it ?

I have writen following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE json::text <> '[]'::text
```

Where I am able to filter empty elements  which starts with {}. but still seeing [].

Comment: In other words: you want to remove *empty elements*?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove empty elements. I don't know why it is coming but when I want to query it, I don't want empty elements.

Comment: The real question is: why are you sometimes inserting an empty JSON object and sometimes and empty JSON _array_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very easy, just select all rows that don't contain those values:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
WHERE json :: text NOT IN ('{}', '[]')
```